# Объясните пожалуйста в чем разница получения ipa файлов?

Tags: ios, xcode

Делаю архив приложения, затем делаю export, нужно получить ipa. Возникает вопрос в чем разница между ними [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Разница в том, что:

1. iOS App Store Deployment - используется distribution profile. Вы можете создать этот ipa и позже отправить при помощи Application Loader. Либо отдать кому-то для этого. В общем, готовые к релизу.
2. Ad Hoc Deployment, используется Ad Hoc distribution profile. Вы можете раздать этот ipa всем устройствам, которые привязаны в Вашему аккаунту (по-моему по 100 каждого типа). Можно установить напрямую с компьютера через iTunes или по ссылке. В общем, для тестирования.
3. Enterprise Deployment" - используется In House distribution profile. Можно устанавливать на устройства компании (имеющие необходимый профиль)
4. Development Deployment - используется development profile. Для разработчиков.

Comment: Спасибо за полезную инфу.